# How do I Insert Seconds along with other timestamp details in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, datetime, timestamp

The Time helper on cakephp does give out only Year, Hour & Min with the Meridian but how do I get the seconds field to be added.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [TimeHelper Format() method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#TimeHelper%3a%3aformat).

```
<?php echo $this->Time->format('F jS, Y h:i:s A', '2011-08-22 11:53:12');?>
//output: August 22nd, 2011 11:53:12 AM
```

`s` will be used to show the `seconds` part from the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass as parameter to display second like AM or pm

```
echo $this->Time->format('F jS, Y h:i A', $post['Post']['created'], null, $user['User']['time_zone']);
// Will display August 22nd, 2011 11:53 PM for a user in GMT+0
// August 22nd, 2011 03:53 PM for a user in GMT-8
// and August 23rd, 2011 09:53 AM GMT+10
```

Also you can refer [Cake Document for Time Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#TimeHelper%3a%3aformat)